# Why Icon is not showing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, favicon

I want to add Icon(favicon) in my project.

so I have added following line in my header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="view/pics/google_favicon.png"/>
```

and added "google_favicon.png" images in pics folder.

**Problem** : It is showing Icon in Mozilla,Chrome and safari but not showing it in IE.

Can any body help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Try clearing the caches on all browsers then see which works. Then check if the path of the image actually does work.

Comment: @ John B :I have Ie 8 version

Comment: @ Sami Dz Hamida : I have done with all (clearing the caches and checked image path also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably cached in browser, try "hard" refresh of page (`ctrl+f5`). (in any browser)

Also try full path `http://www.example.com/view/pics/google_favicon.png`

**edit**

your picture file must be VALID `favicon.ico` file

found a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/a6fb09ef-aa3e-4e9e-be44-edbfad322657/) on this:

1. - Make sure the file is a valid icon file. There are files floating around that have the extension .ico but are not valid icon files. And there are problems (i think) if you convert bmp, jpg, jpeg or gif images to icon files.
2. - Name the file exactly as "favicon.ico" with out the double quotes.
3. - IE8 will never display the icon if the file is on your hard disk. It has to be on the internet. Other browers such as firefox will however show the icon even if they are on your hard disk.
4. - IE8 will not show the icon if u do not have the www in your url address. So
     a - http://yoursitename.com will not work.
     b - http://www.yousitename.com will work.
5. - IE8 downloads the favicon.ico file in the folder.
     C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files
     where user = the name with which u logged in windos xp.

Comment: ::I have added  VALID *.ico file but getting same problem and also done with  (ctrl+f5).

Comment: @ Kyslik :problem is solved by converting  my .png file in to ico extension  thanks...